# Rails ujs response not hitting target

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ujs

The following view has a div for receiving a rails ujs action result

```
<div class='grid-x grid-padding-x'>
  <div class='cell small-12 text-center'>
    <div id="afamilis">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

It is meant to be populater via a `form_with` command that remains remote.  The related `.js.erb` file  has:

```
$(div#afamilis').append('<%= j render('afamily') %>');
```

and the browser console debugger does return a 200 response:

```
$(div#afamilis').append('<div id=\"afamily_128\">\n  <div class=\'grid-x grid-padding-x\'>\n    <div class=\'cell small-12 text-left\'>\n      blurb\n    <\/div>\n  <\/div>\n<\/div>\n');
```

And right after, the browser console debugger complains about

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: private fields are not currently supported
```

then drilling down into the javascript pack for the application.

The browser window does not present the expected HTML block

what is mistaken in the`js.erb` file?

Answer (score 1):

You're missing an opening quote on the selector:

```
$('div#afamilis').append('<%= j render('afamily')
```

Also since ids are unique adding `div` to the selector is highly questionable.

Comment: When you state 'questionable', do you mean 'risky' or more 'pointless' ?

Comment: It's pointless - since there can only be one  element with a specific ID there is no point in specifying what type of element it is.